# Lambda no obtiene el archivo pdf del bucket

Tags: lambda

Tengo una lambda que se dispara al subir un fichero a una carpeta de s3. El código se ejecuta bien hasta el punto de imprimir nombre del bucket y nombre del archivo, pero luego no continúa,la parte print(f"Tamaño del archivo obtenido: {len(pdf_content)} bytes") no la ejecuta, es como si no accediera al archivo pdf, ¿sabeis porqué? . Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

```
    # Extrae la información del evento S3
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    object_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    print(f"Nombre del Bucket: {bucket_name}")
    print(f"Nombre del Archivo (Key): {object_key}")

    # Obtiene el archivo PDF del bucket S3
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
    pdf_content = s3_response['Body'].read()

    # Confirma que el contenido se ha obtenido imprimiendo su tamaño
    print(f"Tamaño del archivo obtenido: {len(pdf_content)} bytes")

    # Convierte el contenido del PDF a texto
    pdf = BytesIO(pdf_content)
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf)
    full_text = ""
    for page_number, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
        page_text = page.extract_text() if page.extract_text() else ""
        full_text += page_text + "\n"  # Añade un salto de línea entre las páginas
        print(f"Texto extraído de la página {page_number + 1}: {page_text}")  # Imprime el texto de cada página

    # Verifica si se extrajo algún texto
    if not full_text.strip():
        print("No se pudo extraer texto del archivo PDF.")
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps(f'No se pudo extraer texto del archivo {object_key}')
        }
    else:
        print("Extracción de texto exitosa. Aquí hay un fragmento del contenido extraído:")
        print(full_text[:500])  # Imprime los primeros 500 caracteres del texto extraído

    # Asegúrate de que el texto no esté vacío antes de enviarlo a OpenSearch
    if not full_text.strip():
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps(f'No se pudo extraer texto del archivo {object_key}')
        }

    # Crea el documento JSON para enviar a OpenSearch
    document = json.dumps({'bucket': bucket_name, 'filename': object_key, 'content': full_text})
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

    # URL para el índice de OpenSearch
    url = f'https://vpc-opensearch-cluster-7ng7olb5klv3cy4q.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/uploaded_files/_doc'

    # Envía el documento a OpenSearch
    response = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, data=document, headers=headers)

    print(response.text)  # Imprime la respuesta de OpenSearch

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(f'Contenido del archivo {object_key} enviado')
    }
```